# Multiple, random DNS lookups for assets from the same subdomain

Tags: performance, optimization, dns, google-chrome-devtools, pagespeed

I was checking load performance of a website, and could see there are multiple DNS lookups for the assets even if its all hosted in the same subdomain. Also this is random, one asset might have DNS lookup in one load, but it might not have in another. (Attaching screenshots of the network tab)

What would be the cause of this behavior and how to fix this?

Load 1
[image: Network Request 1]

Load 2
[image: Network Request 2]

Comment: Your question is off topic here as not related to programming. Have a look at [sf], [su] or [webmasters.se] but read their help section first to see what is on topic. Also as for the question itself, it may not be clear why you jump to the conclusion of "there are multiple DNS lookups" just based on your images. Also it is best if the question stands alone, without images. There are also a lot of details missing, like which browser it is, what DNS resolver it uses (DOH or not?), etc.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek This question is more towards web developers familiar with chrome devtools than server folks. Orange / Purple section in waterfall chart shows DNS lookup. Also have tagged Google chrome devtools in question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think DevTools will give you the information you need to debug this. I think you'll need to dig into Chrome's internal tools. [NetLog](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/netlog) looks relevant.

This blog post also looks relevant: [Google Chrome and (weird) DNS requests](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Google+Chrome+and+%28weird%29+DNS+requests/10312)

If you do find an answer please ping me in the comments. There may be some information that we *should* be exposing in DevTools that we're currently not.